# How to suppress "warning" using Selenium::Remote::Driver?

Tags: selenium, perl, warnings, suppress-warnings, selenium-remotedriver

```
no warnings;
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
 
my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new;
$driver->get('https://www.crawler-test.com/');
$driver->find_element_by_xpath('//a[.="text not found"]');
```

How can I get the above code **not** to print this warning:

> Error while executing command: no such element: Unable to locate
> element: //a[.="text not found"]

According to the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver#find_element_by_xpath), the function issues a "warning" if there is no element found, but having `no warnings;` in the script does not suppress it.

How can I suppress this "warning"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `find_element` instead of `find_element_by_xpath`. The former throws an exception instead of issuing a warning. You can catch these exceptions using the following wrappers:

```
sub nf_find_element {
   my $node;
   if (!eval {
      $node = $web_driver->find_element(@_);
      return 1;  # No exception.
   }) {
      return undef if $@ =~ /Unable to locate element|An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters/;
      die($@);
   }

   return $node;
}


sub nf_find_elements {
   my $nodes;
   if (!eval {
      $nodes = $web_driver->find_elements(@_);
      return 1;  # No exception.
   }) {
      return undef if $@ =~ /Unable to locate element|An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters/;
      die($@);
   }

   return wantarray ? @$nodes : $nodes;
}


sub nf_find_child_element {
   my $node;
   if (!eval {
      $node = $web_driver->find_child_element(@_);
      return 1;  # No exception.
   }) {
      return undef if $@ =~ /Unable to locate element|An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters/;
      die($@);
   }

   return $node;
}


sub nf_find_child_elements {
   my $nodes;
   if (!eval {
      $nodes = $web_driver->find_child_elements(@_);
      return 1;  # No exception.
   }) {
      return undef if $@ =~ /Unable to locate element|An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters/;
      die($@);
   }

   return wantarray ? @$nodes : $nodes;
}
```

`nf` stands for "non-fatal".

Written for Selenium::Chrome, but should work with Selenium::Remote::Driver as well.

Comment: `find_element_by_xpath` issues a warning. `find_element` will croak.

Answer (score 3):

> According to the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver#find_element_by_xpath), the function issues a "warning" if there is no element found, but having `no warnings;` in the script does not suppress it.

That's right. The `warnings` pragma is lexical. Adding `no warnings` to your code will only affect your code. It won't turn off warnings in other modules that your code uses. As [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) says:

> This pragma works just like the "strict" pragma. This means that the scope of the warning pragma is limited to the enclosing block. It also means that the pragma setting will not leak across files (via "use", "require" or "do"). This allows authors to independently define the degree of warning checks that will be applied to their module.